# I am having trouble when I run the java application and it can't execute as I expect

Tags: java

My application cannot find the roommate I added to the room, see sequence:

```
Please select one of the following options:
Add a room in the apartment[1]
Search for a room in the apartment[2]
Add a roommate to an existing room[3]
Check if a room has a roommate[4]
Count the number of existing rooms that have roommates living in them[5]
3
What is the name of this roommate?
kack
What is the surname of thid roommata?
han
What is the age of this roommate?
20
Which room you want to add this roommate in?[A]/[B]/[C]
b
The roommate was added to the room!
Do you want to continue using the App? (Y/N)
y
Please select one of the following options:
Add a room in the apartment[1]
Search for a room in the apartment[2]
Add a roommate to an existing room[3]
Check if a room has a roommate[4]
Count the number of existing rooms that have roommates living in them[5]
4
What is the ID of the room?[A]/[B]/[C]
b
Sorry! There is no roommate in this room.
```

I am not sure where I have to rewrite. I want to know which part is wrong and how I should rewrite my code. The code is following, and the first part is to add roommate and the second part is to check if there is a roommate in the room:

```java
public boolean addRoommate(String pName, String pSurname, int pAge, char pID) {
    boolean response = false;

    if (roomA != null && roomA.getID() == (pID)) {
        Roommate newRoommate = new Roommate(pName, pSurname, pAge);
        response = true;

    } else if (roomB != null && roomB.getID() == (pID)) {
        Roommate newRoommate = new Roommate(pName, pSurname, pAge);
        response = true;

    } else if (roomC != null && roomC.getID() == (pID)) {
        Roommate newRoommate = new Roommate(pName, pSurname, pAge);
        response = true;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Here is the second part of the code, which is where I check for roommate:

```java
public Roommate checkRoommate(char pID) {
    Roommate response = null;

    if (roomA != null && roomA.getID() == (pID) && roomA.getRoommate() != null) {
        response = roomA.getRoommate();
    } else if (roomB != null && roomB.getID() == (pID) && roomB.getRoommate() != null) {
        response = roomB.getRoommate();
    } else if (roomC != null && roomC.getID() == (pID) && roomC.getRoommate() != null) {
        response = roomC.getRoommate();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: You don't put the roommates you have created into any of the rooms, you make the object with `new` and then throw it away again

Comment: How should I put the roommate in the room? I have no idea what to do..

Comment: @Kristin Weng You will need to add a list of roommates to your Room object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the rommate into a rool, for example this way:

```
roomA.setRoomMate(newRoommate)
```

Comment: Do I write in a right way? It still tells me the room do not have roommate.
 if(roomA != null && roomA.getID() == (pID)){
   Roommate newRoommate = new Roommate(pName, pSurname, pAge);
   roomA.setRoommate(newRoommate);
   response = true;
 }

Comment: Execute it in a debugger line by line, then you can check the content of your objects. I can't provide more help with this little fragment of code.